# Lightning Custom Component Edit Override Not Loading

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a custom lightning component that I am using to override the edit action for a custom object. I go to record or the view page of the record, click on the Edit button. a new tab get created but sometimes it doesn`t load my component. I click on the component or rather the tab header and the component loads fine.

When I look at the Lightning inspector, I see the error as shown below.

Has anyone faced something similar?

[image: see the lightning getComponent call in error]

Comment: The multiple asynchronous calls used can result in failures due to the timing of responses. Suggest you also examine the JavaScript console when things goes wrong for errors there. You can also use your browser's JavaScript debugger.

Comment: Hi Keith, Thanks. I did, there is nothing in the console. I even have a debug in the init handler for my component, but the debugger is never invoked till i click on the tab header again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help.

I found the issue. One of the attribute definitions was incorrect for the datatable component I was using. The fact that the error only came up on the first load and worked on the second load, disoriented me from the right path.